# Insert carriage returns in Jinja template rendered with Ansible

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I am writing an Ansible template for a CSV file with  very long lines:

```
{{ hostvars[h]['myvar'][0]['firstvar'] | default('foo') }},{{ hostvars[h]['myvar'][0]['secondvar'] | default('bar') }},{{ hostvars[h]['myvar'][0]['thirdvar'] | default('baz') }}, {# ... #}
```

I'd like to split the lines for readability (after the `,`), but this also insert carriage returns into the template output, breaking it.
How can carriage returns be inserted in the line without appearing in the output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Jinja's [*whitespace control*](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.1.x/templates/#whitespace-control) for this use case:

```
{{ hostvars[h]['myvar'][0]['firstvar'] | default('foo') }},
{{- hostvars[h]['myvar'][0]['secondvar'] | default('bar') }},
{{- hostvars[h]['myvar'][0]['thirdvar'] | default('baz') }}
```

Or you can use the fact that a block can be wrapped on multiple lines without causing any blanks:

```
{{ 
  hostvars[h]['myvar'][0]['firstvar'] | default('foo') 
}},{{ 
  hostvars[h]['myvar'][0]['secondvar'] | default('bar') 
}},{{ 
  hostvars[h]['myvar'][0]['thirdvar'] | default('baz') 
}}
```

---

Side note: using the [*dot notation*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/faq.html#ansible-allows-dot-notation-and-array-notation-for-variables-which-notation-should-i-use), when accessing attributes of a dictionary could also lighten a bit the syntax:

```
{{ hostvars[h]['myvar'][0]['firstvar'] | default('foo') }}
```

could also be written

```
{{ hostvars[h].myvar.0.firstvar | default('foo') }}
```